# Question about Linked List variable assignments

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

When reversing a singly linked-list, I am running into some trouble with variables changing.

```
def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    current = head
    prev = None
    while head:
        current.next = prev  # why does this line set head equal to [1] on the first iteration?
        prev = current
        head = head.next
        current = head
    return prev
```

The only time I change head is when assigning head = head.next. Changing current.next shouldn't affect head. So why does the head variable change on the commented line?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: But in the previous iteration, you did `current = head`, so that assigning to `current.next` is *also* assigning to `head.next`.

Comment: So this is just since python is "pass by object-reference"? In a language with pass by value or pass by reference assigning to `current.next` wouldn't assign to `head.next` as well correct?

Comment: Since this doesn't involve parameter passing, it isn't really about evaluation strategy, more the semantics of assignment. But this would work the same in many common languages, Java, JavaScript, Ruby etc